# Не появляется Notification в Android 11 (sdk 30)

Tags: java, android, kotlin, android-notification

Notification работал отлично, появлялся (sdk 28, android 9). Решила попробовать на эмуляторе под 11 андроид, как следствие уведомления не появляются.

```
private void createNotificationChannel(){
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O){
            NotificationChannel channel1 = new
                    NotificationChannel(CHANNEL_ID_1, "Channel(1)", NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_HIGH);
            channel1.setDescription("Channel 1 Dec..");

            NotificationChannel channel2 = new
                    NotificationChannel(CHANNEL_ID_2, "Channel(2)", NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_HIGH);
            channel2.setDescription("Channel 2 Dec..");

            NotificationManager notificationManager = getSystemService(NotificationManager.class);
            notificationManager.createNotificationChannel(channel1);
            notificationManager.createNotificationChannel(channel2);
        }
    }

void showNotification(int playPauseBtn){
        
        ...

        Notification notification = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this, CHANNEL_ID_2)
                .setSmallIcon(playPauseBtn)
                .setLargeIcon(thumb)
                .setContentTitle(musicFiles.get(position).getTitle())
                .setContentText(musicFiles.get(position).getArtist())
                .addAction(R.drawable.ic_skip_previous, "Previous", prevPending)
                .addAction(playPauseBtn, "Pause", pausePending)
                .addAction(R.drawable.ic_skip_next, "Next", nextPending)
                .setStyle(new androidx.media.app.NotificationCompat.MediaStyle()
                        .setMediaSession(new MediaSessionCompat(getBaseContext(), TAG).getSessionToken()))
                .setPriority(NotificationCompat.PRIORITY_HIGH)
                .setContentIntent(contentPending)
                .setDeleteIntent(deletePending)
                .setOnlyAlertOnce(true)
                .setVisibility(NotificationCompat.VISIBILITY_PUBLIC)
                .build();
        startForeground(2, notification);
    }
```

Comment: Так запустите теперь уведомление: NotificationManager nm (NotificationManager) context.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE); nm.notify(notify_id, notification); Или еще лучше вот скорее всего Вам поможет: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6397754/android-implementing-startforeground-for-a-service

Comment: Похоже Вы перепутали кислое с пресным. Что вам нужно, запустить уведомление или сервис переднего плана?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Спасибо за ответ, но ошибка оказалась в другом.

Это находится в стиле:

```
 .setStyle(new androidx.media.app.NotificationCompat.MediaStyle()
     .setMediaSession(new MediaSessionCompat(
         getBaseContext(), TAG).getSessionToken()))
```

Так делать нельзя, прокатит только до 11 андроид. Нужно сделать так:

```
.setStyle(new androidx.media.app.NotificationCompat.MediaStyle())
```

Answer (score 0):

build.grandle SDK не забыли поправить?

```
compileSdkVersion 31
minSdkVersion 25
targetSdkVersion 31
```

На Андроид 12 работает

```
     try {
        notificationManager = (NotificationManager) this.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
            notificationChannel_main = new NotificationChannel("ID", "VestaXR_main", NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_LOW);
            notificationManager.createNotificationChannel(notificationChannel_main);
            builder_main = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this, notificationChannel_main.getId())
                    .setContentTitle("")
                    .setSound(null)
                    .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_stat_onesignal_default)
                    .setContentText("");
        } else {
            builder_main = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this);
        }
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
            startForeground(1, builder_main.build());
        }
    } catch (RuntimeException e) {
    }
```

Comment: Почему именно 31, а не 30? У меня стоит 30.

Comment: 31 это 12. 30 и 31 в этом случае одинаковы (вроде как)

Comment: Спасибо за Ваш ответ, но, к сожалению, мне он не помог. Я не вижу различий между вашим кодом и моим, не могу понять где ошибка.

Comment: Вы его запускали?